# JMESPath query expression with bash variable

Tags: bash, aws-cli, jmespath

Messing around with a simple aws cli query to check for the existence of a Lambda function and echo the associated role if it exists:

```
#!/bin/bash

fname=$1
role=$(aws lambda list-functions --query 'Functions[?FunctionName == `$fname`].Role' --output text)

echo "$fname role: $role"
```

However, $fname appears to be resolving to an empty string in the aws command.  I've tried escaping the back ticks, swapping ` to ' and a miriad of other thrashing edits (and yes, I'm passing a string on the cl when invoking the script :)

How do I properly pass a variable into JMESPath query inside a bash script?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Because the whole JMESPath expression is enclosed in single quotes, bash is not expanding the `$fname` variable.  To fix this you can surround the value with double quotes and then use single quotes ([raw string literals](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#raw-string-literals)) for the `$fname` var:

```
aws lambda list-functions --query "Functions[?FunctionName == '$fname'].Role" --output text
```

Answer (score 11):

Swapping the  backticks to single quotes, didn't work for me... :(

But escaping the backticks works :)

Here are my outputs:

```
aws elbv2 describe-listeners --load-balancer-arn $ELB_ARN --query "Listeners[?Port == '$PORT'].DefaultActions[].TargetGroupArn | [0]"
```

null

```
aws elbv2 describe-listeners --load-balancer-arn $ELB_ARN --query "Listeners[?Port == \`$PORT\`].DefaultActions[].TargetGroupArn | [0]"
```

"arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-southeast-2:1234567:targetgroup/xxx"

Comment: That's because raw quotes (single quotes) *always create strings*, and if `Listeners[].Port` is a number, then a string won't match. That is, '1234' is really short for \`"1234"\`.

Answer (score 1):

7 years later and same problem.
I finally figured it out by trying some dumb syntaxes.

found out the one that worked for me: simply add simple quotes inbetween the bacckquotes.
It's working because bash evaluates the first string (`` Functions[?FunctionName == ` `` ), the variable `$fname` and then the last string `` `].Role ``

```
#!/bin/bash

fname=$1
role=$(aws lambda list-functions --query 'Functions[?FunctionName == `'$fname'`].Role' --output text)

echo "$fname role: $role"
```

And here you are !